# A*, Uniform cost and Greedy Best first search implementations

Tags: java, algorithm, object-oriented, graph, a-star

I am writing the code for A*, Uniform cost search and Greedy best first search algorithms in Java. I have finished the code which is working fine but I have used a bit different design strategy while writing this code and I want this code to be as efficient and as clean as possible so I could really use your help.

The basic idea I have used is all 3 are best first search algorithms, just the difference is that they way in which they put nodes in queue. For A* the queue priority is based on distance plus heuristics value, while for greedy it's just the heuristic value, so I wrote code for BestFirstSearch and wrote a different Queue for each algorithm. Below is my code

***BestFirstSearch.Java***

```
import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class BestFirstSearch {
    Graph g;
    /* Dont set infinity to Integer.MAX_VALUE it will result 
       into integer overflow when you add heuristics cost
       into it */    
    int INFINITY = 100000007;

    /* Priority queue for holding pairs of vertex id */
    BestFirstSearchQueue queue;

    /* Previous node in path */
    int previousNode[];

    /* Distance of this node from source */
    int shortestDistance[];

    /* Debugging related data */
    ArrayList<Integer> exploredCities;

    public BestFirstSearch(Graph g, BestFirstSearchQueue queue) {
        this.g = g;
        this.queue = queue;
        previousNode = new int[g.getV()];
        shortestDistance = new int[g.getV()];
        for (int i = 0; i < g.getV(); i++) {
            previousNode[i] = -1;
            shortestDistance[i] = INFINITY;
        }
        exploredCities = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    private void explore(int currNode, ArrayList<Integer> adjList) {
        for (int succesor : adjList) {
            int currDist = shortestDistance[currNode] + 
                g.getEdgeCost(currNode, succesor);            
            if (shortestDistance[succesor] > currDist) {
                // Distance should never contain heuristic cost
                shortestDistance[succesor] = currDist;
                /* Update if already exitst else add*/
                queue.add(succesor, currDist);
                previousNode[succesor] = currNode;
            }
        }
        exploredCities.add(currNode);
    }

    public SearchData getPathData(int src, int dst) {
        ArrayList<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int curr = dst;
        while (curr != src && previousNode[curr] != -1) {
            path.add(curr);
            curr = previousNode[curr];
        }
        path.add(src);
        Collections.reverse(path);
        SearchData sData = new SearchData(shortestDistance[dst],
                                          path,
                                          exploredCities);
        return sData;
    }

    public SearchData search(int src, int dst) {
        shortestDistance[src] = 0;
        queue.add(src, 0);
        while (!queue.isEmpty() &&
               queue.peek() != dst) {
            int currNode = queue.poll();
            ArrayList<Integer> adjList = g.getAdjVertices(currNode);
            explore(currNode, adjList);
        }
        return getPathData(src, dst);
    }

}
```

**BestFirstSearchQueue.java  - interface for API**

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
public interface BestFirstSearchQueue {
    /* Provides a common interface for all best first search graph
       queues. Implement this interface according to search 
       strategy (viz. A*, Uniform cost, Greedy) and pass this queue
       to BestFirstSearch Class. */
    /* This queue interface works on vertex id of each node, basically
       it can store a particular vertex with its cost and retrieve these
       values as per request from search function. The heuristic calculations
       happen inside this class - search function doesn't need to 
       know about these heuristics */

    /* This is the Priority queue used by all classes, comparator will 
       change */

    int initialCapacity = 512;
    /* Adds a new vertex into queue with given cost if its not already
       present, if it is already present in queue then replace it with 
       this value */
    public void add(int vertex, int cost);

    /* returns vertex id of top element of queue */
    public int poll();

    /* removes and returns topmost element of queue */
    public int peek();

    /* checks if queue is empty */
    public boolean isEmpty();
}
```

***AStarSearchQueue.java***

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

class AStarSearchQueue implements BestFirstSearchQueue {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = null;
    /* Hashmap for storing path distance to a node */
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> distanceMap;
    /* Hashmap for storing heuristic value for a node */
    HashMap<Integer, Double> heuristicsMap;

    public AStarSearchQueue() {
        queue = new PriorityQueue<>(initialCapacity,
                                    new AStarCostComparator());
        distanceMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public AStarSearchQueue(HashMap<Integer, Double> heuristics) {
        this();
        heuristicsMap = heuristics;
    }

    public AStarSearchQueue(double heuristics[]) {
        this();
        heuristicsMap = new HashMap<>();
        int vertex = 0;
        for(double cost : heuristics) {
            heuristicsMap.put(vertex++, cost);
        }
    }

    public void add(int vertex, int value) {
        if (queue.contains(vertex)) {
            queue.remove(vertex);
            distanceMap.remove(vertex);
        }         
        distanceMap.put(vertex, value);
        queue.add(vertex);
    }

    public int poll() {
        return queue.poll();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return queue.isEmpty();
    }

    public int peek() {
        return queue.peek();
    }

    /* Comparator for A* search strategy */
    class AStarCostComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            double cost1 = distanceMap.get(o1);
            double cost2 = distanceMap.get(o2);
            cost1 += heuristicsMap.get(o1);
            cost2 += heuristicsMap.get(o2);
            if (cost1 > cost2)
                return 1;
            else if (cost1 == cost2)
                return 0;
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for UniformSearchQueue.java and GreedySearchQueue.java is almost same as AStarSearchQueue.java except that it has different comparator class which compares heuristics (for greedy) and cost distance (for uniform).

And I create Object for BestFirstSearch as follows:

```
    BestFirstSearch bfs = new BestFirstSearch(usa.getGraph(),
                                              new AStarSearchQueue(usa.getHeuristics(src)));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Missing classes

This is not a complete code. It is missing `Graph` and `SearchData`. Please provide those. In particular, I'm not sure what `Graph.getV()` does, so even though I belieave there's a weak point in `BestFirstSearch` that relates to it, I will not investigate.

### `AStarSearchQueue` is not a `Queue`

But it could be. Why make it have a delegate `PriorityQueue` field, and not simply extend `PriorityQueue<Integer>` ? If you're not going to change implementations, this will be more natural, and reduce the objects count.

And don't worry, to your `BestFirstSearch` class, these queues will not be `PriorityQueue`s, but `BestFirstSearchQueue`s, so not fear of exposing to many methods.

### `BestFirstSearchQueue` interface has a constant `initialCapacity` field

This is considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320588/interfaces-with-static-fields-in-java-for-sharing-constants/320642#320642).
If you're an interface, you have NO IDEA what the implementations are. How come do you know in advance what kind of initial size is good? It is not only implementation-dependant, it is also instance-dependant (if my problem is small, why do i want 512? if my problem is huge, why limit to 512?). This is arbitrary, and should go.

### Units

Why are your distances stored as `Integers`, when your heuristic allows `Double`? Make it all store `Double`s.

### Declaration types

Always declare Objects as being of the highest-level class that you can get away with. For instance:

```
ArrayList<Integer> exploredCities;
```

Must become:

```
List<Integer> exploredCities;
```

This way you'll be able to easily switch implementation later on.